# Delete multiple class members fast (regex? visual studio?)

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio, macros, notepad++

Does anyone have any idea, how it is possible to delete multiple class members in a fast way? I have some hundred properties I want to delete. These were generated when creating the class from an XSD:

```
public bool propnameSpecified { ... }
```

I don't like to have these, I don't need them. I had a look in the class view if I could mark them and delete like this. I tried regex, but I am, hmm..., not realy a regex geek ;-)

Has anyone a better idea than deleting by hand from source file or writing a script to this?

Any idea appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It's probably easier to [regenerate the classes using the `/fields` option of xsd.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), that way the properties are not generated in the first place. There is no easy way to reliably remove these generated properties in the right way using a regular expression.

Comment: I would do that if there wouldn't be several changes at names and structures have been done in the class... But thanks anyway, now I know how to avoid these properties next time

Answer (score 0):

I'm no good with Regex either, but as long as they're only a single line, try this:

`(public|private|protected)+ .+ .+ \{ (get|set).+ \}`